# usage of make_shared and allocate_shared in boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm not able to understand the boost documentation on how to use `make_shared` and `allocate_shared` to initialize shared arrays and pointers:

```
shared_ptr<int> p_int(new int); // OK
shared_ptr<int> p_int2 = make_shared<int>(); // OK
shared_ptr<int> p_int3 = allocate_shared(int);  // ??


shared_array<int> sh_arr(new int[30]); // OK
shared_array<int> sh_arr2 = make_shared<int[]>(30); // ??
shared_array<int> sh_arr3 = allocate_shared<int[]>(30); // ??
```

I'm trying to learn the correct syntax to initialize the above variables commented as `// ??`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`allocate_shared` is used just like `make_shared`, except that you pass an allocator as the first argument.

```
boost::shared_ptr<int> p_int(new int);
boost::shared_ptr<int> p_int2 = boost::make_shared<int>();

MyAllocator<int> alloc;
boost::shared_ptr<int> p_int3 = boost::allocate_shared<int>(alloc);
```

There is no `make` function for `boost::shared_array`, so the only way to make one is allocating the memory manually:

```
boost::shared_array<int> sh_arr(new int[30]);
```

But `boost::make_shared` etc. support array types - either one of unknown size, or one of fixed size - in both cases a `boost::shared_ptr` is returned:

```
boost::shared_ptr<int[]> sh_arr2 = boost::make_shared<int[]>(30);
boost::shared_ptr<int[30]> sh_arr3 = boost::make_shared<int[30]>();
```

Note that `std::shared_ptr` does *not* support arrays at this time.

Comment: **boost::shared_ptr<int[]> sh_arr2 = boost::make_shared<int[]>(30);** will memory be freed correctly in this case? and what do you mean by "does not support arrays at this time"? because I was able to fill in each element and access each one with for loop and [] operator...

Comment: @codekiddy 1) If you are using a sufficiently recent version of boost (1.53 or later), then the memory will be freed correctly. 2) I was talking about `std::shared_ptr`, the one that came in the standard library. That one doesn't support arrays as of C++14 (a proposal to add array support was voted into a draft technical specification).

Comment: Oh, **std::shared_ptr**, I see now, Thank you for additional info. very useful!